# Inheritance for class with the same name but different namespace c++

Tags: c++

Is it possible to inherit from the class with the same name, but in different namespace and how to achieve it?

For example I have the following structure:

```
   namespace general {
           namespace gui {
             struct GUI {

        };
   }}
```

can I do:

```
 namespace proxy {
          namespace gui {
            struct GUI : general::gui::GUI {
    
          };
     }}
```

Or / and there should be another way to doing this (short of actually naming the class / structure differently)?

Update based on [Pete's Becker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1593860/pete-becker) comment.

The current way it is structured is like that:

**gui.h**

```
    #include "world.h"
     
namespace general {
               namespace gui {
                 struct GUI {
    
            };
   }}
```

**world.h**

```
namespace general {

    namespace world {

        struct World {};
}}
```

**proxy.h**

```
 namespace proxy {
          namespace gui {
            struct GUI : general::gui::GUI {

          };
     }}
```

My understanding is that compiler looks at world.h, doesn't find general::gui and complains with

```
proxy.h(17,30): error C2039: 'gui': is not a member of 'general'
world.h(4): message : see declaration of 'general'
```

If I add

```
namespace world {
    
            struct World {};
    }}
```

to **gui.h** or other way around, it will most probably work. Just was confused of why do I need to do it.

Update2 (with .cpp files):

**world.cpp**

```
#include "world.h"

namespace general {
    namespace world {
                    World{
```

**gui.cpp**

```
#include "gui.h"

namespace general {
    namespace gui {
```

**proxy.cpp**

```
#include "proxy.h"

namespace proxy {
    namespace gui {
```

On the .cpp files side, all of them are just including their corresponding header files. This is the general rule.

Plus here is the (relevant) header file chain, which most certainly where the problem is:

```
goal.h    includes      world.h and proxy.h
gui.h     includes      world.h and goal.h
menu.h    includes      goal.h
world.h - includes nothing
proxy.h - includes nothing
```

Update3: Fixed now by moving proxy.h into gui.h temporarily and in the process uncovering a dependency error. Will move the files back and just wanted to confirm that the issue was with the interdependencies of the .h files.

Comment: Have you tried doing that and seeing what happens?

Comment: ShadowMitia is right: Try it and see where that gets you.
That said, to my knowledge, there is absolutely no problem with this kind of inheritance, however you should be careful with your file naming. Debuggers tend to only look at the filename (at least the one I use does), which means that your breakpoints may trigger where you don't want them to.

Comment: error C2499: 'proxy::gui::GUI': a class cannot be its own base class.

It works if I remove the inheritance

Comment: If you put those two code snippets into a single source file, in the same order as you've shown in the question, the code should compile just fine. Any problems you're having are because of the way the code is structured, not from the use of inheritance itself. So you have to revise your question to contain the smallest code you can come up with that shows the problem.

Comment: Please post the .cpp file. And you need to improve your understanding of include files. #include actually does not do anything more than replacing the `#include` line with the contents of the file. #include is a PREPROCESSOR statement. The Compiler itself does not really do anything with it. Read up Preprocessor statements.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Will have a look. Also, updated with .cpp file, which actually only include it's corresponding header and the .h files relevant to the question chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. If you are getting an error, there is something in your code you have not posted here, such as a using namespace statement.

`proxy::gui::GUI` and `general::gui::GUI` are two entirely different classes. The fact that both end with `GUI` says nothing at all.

The full/complete name of the class is always the full name including namespaces.

That's the point of namespaces. They were invented to prevent name clashes between different libraries. Imagine you have library of vendor "A" which includes a class `GUI`. Imagine you want to use this library in your own code, where you also have defined a class `GUI`. Without namespaces these names would clash and you would be forced to rename your own class to use the library.

But with namespaces all is good. `A::GUI` is something different than `yourcode::GUI` or just plain `GUI`.

So

```
namespace general { namespace gui {
   class GUI {};
}}

namespace proxy { namespace gui {
   class GUI:public general::gui::GUI {};
}}
```

will / should work.

---

#### Update (after the .cpp has been posted)

- proxy.cpp includes proxy.h
- proxy.h refers to `general::gui::GUI`

but `general::gui` is not visible to proxy.h. It has not been included.  Neither proxy.cpp nor proxy.h "known" anything about a `general` or a `general::gui`.

That is exactly what the compiler error message is saying.

```
proxy.h(17,30): error C2039: 'gui': is not a member of 'general'
```

The `gui` thing you are trying to access (in the inheritance) is not a member of a `general` thing -- at least not to proxy.cpp or proxy.h. These two files know only about a namespace `proxy` and a namespace `gui`. Nothing else. Hence the error.

It is not enough to declare a `namespace general` or `namespace gui` in any header file. Header files don't do anything by themselves.

Add a

```
#include "gui.h"
```

to your proxy.h and it should work.

But beware of circular references.

Read more about includes (and include guards) before continuing.

Comment: Thank you for this. It seems that it complains about the gui not being a member of general because the way the h files are setup. Still I don't quite understand why it matters as gui doesn't need to have a definition, right? It is a path to a class, so this kind of error doesn't make sense:  'gui': is not a member of 'general' as 'gui' is a namespace, not a class...

Comment: The way it is set is that there another .h file, where there is no namespace general{namespace gui ......}, but there is namespace general {namespace world{.....}}. But why does it matter as the above proxy definition is capable of seeing general::gui::GUI class?

Comment: You can't inherit from a class unless the compiler knows its definition. It sounds like you have a mutual dependency between headers that needs breaking.

Comment: I can see that it is the case, just not quite clear of why namespace definition = to class definition. I mean why can't I have general::gui and general::world for example in two different .h files? Here both gui and world are namespaces. I thought that namespaces are exactly what the answer above suggests, i.e. separators / groups for the different classes.

Comment: You cannot (never ever) inherit from a class unless the headerfile for this class is included _before_ the definition.

Comment: @Irbis77 -- the problem that you seem to be running into isn't about whether it's okay to use the same name in multiple namespaces -- it absolutely is. It looks like there's a problem in the way your code is structured, and that doesn't show up in the snippets in the question. So you have to revise your question to contain the smallest code you can come up with that shows the problem.